# How to generate Access token for dropbox API automatically through code?

Tags: java, api, salesforce, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to create folders & sub-folders in my dropbox account. I am using Dropbox APIs to achieve this task. Currently I am using the generated access token from my dropbox account which I got when I clicked on the Generate button. Is there a way to generate this access token automatically through the code?

Answer (score 0):

No, acquiring access to a Dropbox account requires manual user authorization; this can't be fully automated. The app can store and re-use the resulting access/refresh token though, without having the user manually re-authorize it each time though. Refer to [the OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization) for more information.